# How to make Python print the URL and its corresponding status code?

Tags: python, http, python-requests, http-status-code-404, status

I'd like to have Python go through a text file and check the status code of each URL in that file. Then, Python can make a new text file and input in each line the URL and its corresponding status code. How can I do that? This is my incomplete script below:

```
import requests
with open("jack.txt") as fid:
    url_lines = set(fid)
for url in url_lines:
    response = requests.get(url)
    status_code = response.status_code
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
import csv

# open the file in the write mode
# or rename the url-status-codes.csv to a filename you want
f = open('url-status-codes.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='')
# create the csv writer
writer = csv.writer(f)

with open("jack.txt") as fid:
    url_lines = set(fid)
for url in url_lines:
    response = requests.get(url)
    status_code = response.status_code
    # if you want it in a format of url, status_code
    writer.writerow([url, status_code])
    # but you want just a space after, uncomment this
    # writer.writerow([url + " " + status_code])

# close the file
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're really close; one approach you could take is to save all the results in a list, open a new file and write out the contents of said list:

```py
import requests

with open("jack.txt") as fid, open("results.txt", "w") as fout:
    url_lines = [line.strip() for line in fid]
    results = [(url, requests.get(url).status_code) for url in url_lines]

    for url, status_code in results:
        fout.write(f"{url} {status_code}\n")
```

If `jack.txt` is:

```
https://google.com
https://bing.com
https://stackoverflow.com/404
```

`results.txt` results in:

```
https://google.com 200
https://bing.com 200
https://stackoverflow.com/404 404
```